# A huge non-normal, heteroscedastic dataset with multiple groups. How to test?

Tags: r, nonparametric, biostatistics, heteroscedasticity

I have a dataset with approximately 38,000 measurements of sizes of cysts from 64 kidneys from 5 different groups.
We have a hypothesis that the distribution of the sizes (small to huge) is different between the groups. Perhaps this could be represented by mean, median, or other means.

The data has an enormously large number of very small cysts with a continuum to far fewer huge cysts. By its nature, the frequency of sizes is extremely left-skewed and non-normal. I transformed the size data (log10) to better distribute the data. But the nature of the data is still apparent. It's just how it is!

[image]

Generating a linear model for size vs the groups [lm(size ~ groups, data=cyst.data)] and plotting the fitted vs residual values shows heavily skewed residuals

[image]

with their distribution fanning outwards the larger the fitted values are. The residuals really don't fit the model well:

[image]

Running either a levene or bartlett's test on the data indicates the variances are significantly different. I don't know if the total sample number of ~30000 could be influencing these tests.

So here I am, like a fish out of water.

I have gone down some rabbit holes and have seen tests that do not assume normality or homoscedasticity but neither at the same time.

Kruskal-Wallis - non-normal data but suggested to not to be used for heteroscedastic data (http://www.biostathandbook.com/kruskalwallis.html)

For heteroscedastic data - Welch's ANOVA with Games Howell for pairwise testing - but assumes normality.

Can anyone offer suggestions? I'm not looking for differences in means, medians or distributions specifically; I'm agnostic to be honest. I could also use a Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test to just compare the distributions perhaps, and that might be sufficient.

Ideas?

cheers,
K

Comment: Maybe quantile regression would suit you?

Comment: Your analysis seems to treat all 38,000 cyst sizes as independent. Observations within individual kidneys are likely to be correlated, however, which you need to account for in some way. That admittedly doesn't get to the other problems that you raise for evaluating your hypothesis. Visually, the histograms don't look so different among the groups, with modes all near 0.003 and similar widths and skew.

Comment: @EdM you are correct, my formula in reality is [lm(size ~ groups + kidney.sample + sex, data=cyst.data)] I simplified it for the post. But the appearance of data between the samples is similar, your observations are correct. The nature of the data just looks like this, that is expected because there are few tiny ones, lots of small ones, less large ones.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your input. I've had a try but am running into a singular design matrix wall. I have one continuous variable and multiple factors, and I think this is the issue. I don't think rq (from the R library quantreg) likes my data and I'm not sure how to massage the data to make it work.